# How to convert mm:ss to seconds using momentjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time, momentjs

I am using reactjs. On the frontend I am getting the time in format "mm:ss" example data:

```
const data [{
  duration: "00:10" //I want 10
}, {
  duration: "20:00" //I want 1200
}, {
  duration: "30:00"  // I want 1800
}]
```

I tried this and a lot but could not work

```
moment.duration("30:00").asSeconds()
```

These duration are in mm:ss format and I want them to convert to just seconds. How can I do that either using Javascript or moment js?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That good  moment handle all thing .
try this it would work.

```
moment.duration("whatever time is").asSeconds()
```

or

```
 const Second=(new Date(moment.duration *.1000)).toUTCString().match(/(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/)[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to add hours for the duration to work, you can try this:

```
moment('30:00', 'mm:ss').diff(moment().startOf('day'), 'seconds');
```

Answer (score 1):

The format required for the `duration` method is `hh:mm:ss`. So your code should look something like this:

```js
moment.duration("00:30:00").asSeconds()
```

Note: I tested this on `moment@2.29.4` and it's working as expected.